# Create function with query in model, Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a working function in my controller, but I want to place a part of the code in model, is repeatable and I want to use it in multiple controllers. but witch my current code is not working (no errors).

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   $query = new Question;
   $query->select(
       ['questions.id', 
       'questions.free_text', 
       'questions.title', 
       'questions.created_at',
       'lkp_answers.name as bestMatch',
       ]);
   $query->with(['answer_history']);
   $query->join('lkp_answers', 'lkp_answers.id', '=', 'questions.best_match');
   $query->count_filter($query, $request); //here I try to use it
   return response()->json($query->paginate($request->per_page));
}
```

**Model**

```
public function count_filter($query, $request){
    if($request->sort_by){
        $direction = ($request->sort_direction === 'false') ? 'asc' : 'desc';

        if($request->sort_by === 'best_match'){
            $query->orderBy('lkp_answers.name', $direction);
        }else if ($request->sort_by === 'noneOfTheAbove') {
            $query->withCount(['answer_history AS none' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('answer_type', 'none');

                return $q;
            }])->orderBy('none', $direction);
        } else if ($request->sort_by === 'skipped') {
            $query->withCount(['answer_history AS skipped' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('answer_type', 'skipped');

                return $q;
            }])->orderBy('skipped', $direction);
        }  else if ($request->sort_by === 'totalVotes') {
            $query->withCount(['answer_history AS totalVotes' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('answer_type', '!=','skipped');

                return $q;
            }])->orderBy('totalVotes', $direction);
        } 
        else {
            $query->orderBy($request->sort_by,$direction);
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: There is another option is to make helper function and put that code there so you can use anywhere in project.

Comment: Ok, but that should work from Model too, but if I dd($query->get()), at the beginning of the model function, I don't have the bestMatch, and relationship from join..

Comment: try `$query = $query->count_filter($query, $request);`

Comment: Same result. I don't get values from join..

Comment: @Beusebiu `$query = Helper::count_filter($query, $request);` and make static function on helper file. and call like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the method to the model but you try to call it on an eloquent query. What you need to do is to use another variable for the query:

```
public function index(Request $request, Question $question)
{
   $query = $question->newQuery();
   $query->select(
       ['questions.id', 
       'questions.free_text', 
       'questions.title', 
       'questions.created_at',
       'lkp_answers.name as bestMatch',
       ]);
   $query->with(['answer_history']);
   $query->join('lkp_answers', 'lkp_answers.id', '=', 'questions.best_match');

   $question->count_filter($query, $request)

   return response()->json($query->paginate($request->per_page));
}
```